# Getting a Corba error in IIOP on Simple Java JMX Client connecting to Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

I am testing a simple java client program connecting to weblogic 12c to display some basic JMX MBean, however I keep getting the following error.  I am running the program using the full client libraries generated by weblogic called "wlfullclient.jar". The weblogic server is on a remote VM server running java 1.8 and the client is a PC running also java 1.8. I did some research about similar problems with IIOP that were fixed in previous version of JAVA, I would think this fix would be carried forward to java 1.8 but I am not 100% sure is the same problem. I hope somebody can shed some light to fix this problem.  thanks

```
May 10, 2016 4:49:06 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0 read_value
WARNING: "IOP00810211: (MARSHAL) Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream"
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1010)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.read_Array(ValueHandlerImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:704)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:431)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:105)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1961)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:838)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:828)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:287)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:379)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:542)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at org.omg.stub.javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnection_Stub.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper$13.run(ClientProviderBase.java:1137)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.subject.SubjectManager.runAs(SubjectManager.java:286)
    at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:67)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper.getAttributes(ClientProviderBase.java:1135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.InvocationContextProxyHandler.invoke(ClientProviderBase.java:636)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttributes(RMIConnector.java:931)
    at MyConnection.main(MyConnection.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: weblogic.health.Symptom$Severity; UnsupportedOperationException accessing no-arg constructor
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1471)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:414)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:915)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1457)
    ... 78 more

Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:227)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:80)
    at org.omg.stub.javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnection_Stub.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper$13.run(ClientProviderBase.java:1137)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:368)
    at weblogic.security.subject.SubjectManager.runAs(SubjectManager.java:286)
    at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:67)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.RMIConnectionWrapper.getAttributes(ClientProviderBase.java:1135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.InvocationContextProxyHandler.invoke(ClientProviderBase.java:636)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.getAttributes(RMIConnector.java:931)
    at MyConnection.main(MyConnection.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.valuehandlerReadException(ORBUtilSystemException.java:7004)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1010)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.read_Array(ValueHandlerImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:339)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2033)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:267)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TCUtility.unmarshalIn(TCUtility.java:285)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.AnyImpl.read_value(AnyImpl.java:590)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:704)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(CDRInputStream.java:238)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:431)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.readAny(Util.java:105)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1961)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2254)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1249)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:844)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:838)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:828)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream.java:287)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:379)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:542)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1722)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1240)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:416)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:271)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: weblogic.health.Symptom$Severity; UnsupportedOperationException accessing no-arg constructor
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1471)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:414)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:999)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ObjectStreamClass.newInstance(ObjectStreamClass.java:915)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1457)
```

The sample program is as follow

```
import javax.management.Attribute;
import javax.management.AttributeList;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.naming.Context;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class MyConnection {

    private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
    private static JMXConnector connector;
    private static final ObjectName service = null;
    /*
    * Initialize connection to the Domain Runtime MBean Server.
    */
    public static void initConnection(String hostname, String portString,
                                      String username, String password) throws IOException,
            MalformedURLException {

        String protocol = "IIOP";
        Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(portString);
        int port = portInteger.intValue();
        String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
        String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
        JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname, port,jndiroot + mserver);

        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
        h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,"weblogic.management.remote");
        h.put("jmx.remote.x.request.waiting.timeout", new Long(10000));
        connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
        connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hostname = "10.30.8.63";
        String portString = "7001";
        String username = "weblogic";
        String password = "not4long!";

        MyConnection c= new MyConnection();
        initConnection(hostname, portString, username, password);

        MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

        String[] domains = connection.getDomains();

        for(String d:domains){
            System.out.println(d);
        }

        String bean = "com.bea:Name=JMSReader_jms-servlet!jms-servlet_java_app.weblogic.examples.jms.servletQueue!WseeJMSServer@jms.servletQueue,ServerRuntime=AdminServer,Location=AdminServer,Type=MessageDrivenEJBRuntime,ApplicationRuntime=jms-servlet,WebAppComponentRuntime=AdminServer_/jms-servlet";

        String[] attributes = new String[]{
                "ConnectionStatus",
                "Destination",
                "EJBName",
                "HealthState",
                "JMSConnectionAlive",
                "JmsClientID",
                "LastException",
                "LastExceptionAsString",
                "MDBStatus",
                "Name",
                "Parent",
                "PoolRuntime",
                "ProcessedMessageCount",
                "Resources",
                "SuspendCount",
                "TimerRuntime",
                "TransactionRuntime",
                "Type"};

        AttributeList aList = connection.getAttributes(new ObjectName(bean),attributes);

        for(int i=0;i<aList.size();i++) {

            Object obj = (((Attribute) aList.get(i)).getValue());

            String key = ((Attribute) aList.get(i)).getName();

            System.out.println(key + " " + obj );

        }

        connector.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears  to be a java 1.8 problem. I installed the same weblogic version but using java 1.7 and downgraded the client app to java 1.7 and the problem went away.